# How can I pass a "property-list" object to an iOS Application via Custom URL?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiapplicationdelegate, uiapplication

iOS Gurus,

I'm creating an iOS application that will respond to Custom URLs.  When reading the documentation for handling a custom URL (API doc here: [application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3aopenURL%3asourceApplication%3aannotation%3a)), I see that the 4th argument is an annotation, defined as follows:

> *annotation* 
>  A property-list object supplied by the source application to communicate information to the receiving application.

However, when I look at the method for opening custom URLs (API doc here: [openURL:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/openURL%3a)), there is no way to define a "property-list" object.  You can only specify the URL (which itself may have name/value parameters in the query string).

How can I pass a "property-list" object **in addition** to the URL to an application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The annotation option is for apps that are opened when a user references a document created by that app using a [UIDocumentInteractionController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010403).

If you're looking to launch the app from a custom URL scheme in a UIWebView then this does not pertain to you.

Answer (score 0):

To complete the first part of the answer by @Richard, set the annotation property of the UIDocumentInteractionController with a valid property list prior to calling presentPreviewAnimated:

```
NSURL *fURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Document" withExtension:@"pdf"];
if (fURL) 
{
    UIDocumentInteractionController *dIC;
    dIC = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL: fURL];
    dIC.annotation = @{@"foo": @"bar"};
    [dIC setDelegate:self];
    [dIC presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
}
```